# The divisibility of the product of Pythagorean Theorem by 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

We know that there is a fundamental theorem that is: $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Then it is given that the product of a,b and c are divisible by 5 where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. Using numbers, I know for certain that this is in fact true. But by using $\mod{5}$, I am not certain how I can approach this question.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the possible values of $n^2$ modulo $5$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use the formulas
$$a=m^2-n^2,b=2mn,c=m^2+n^2$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this formula? Is there a specific meaning behind why $a=m^2-n^2$, $b=2mn$ and $c=m^2+n^2$? I do not understand the formula.

Comment: yes you can Show that $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$ is fulfilled!

Answer (score 0):

For any integer $a$, $a^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod{5}$. If any one of the integers $a$ or $b$ is $0 \mod 5$, then $abc \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. So let us consider only the case when $a, b \equiv 1,2,3,4 \pmod{5}$.

If both $a^2,b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, then $c^2 \equiv a^2+b^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$, which cannot be true as the only (non-zero) quadratic residues modulo $5$ are $1,4$. Likewise we can infer that both $a^2,b^2$ cannot be $4 \mod{5}$ either. So one of $a^2$ or $b^2$ has to be one $1 \pmod{5}$ and the other $4 \pmod{5}$, but then $c^2 \equiv a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. Thus $5$ divides at least one of $a,b,c$.